# What is the approximation for $(a x^{-2} + b x^{-4})^{-1}$ for small $x$?

Tags: limits, approximation

Given that $x$ is small (closer to zero), what should be the expression $(a x^{-2} + b x^{-4})^{-1}$ approximated with? Is it $a^{-1} x^2$ or $b^{-1} x^4$ or something else? Here, $a$ and $b$ are positive constants.

Comment: For $x$ near $0,$ the term $bx^{-4}$ is much larger in magnitude (i.e. in absolute value) than $ax^{-2},$ so when adding the two, one ignores $ax^{-2}.$ So to a first approximation we have $(bx^{-4})^{-1} = b^{-1}x^4.$

Comment: But for small $x$, doesn't it seem that $a^{-1}x^2$ will be dominant?

Comment: Note that small + large is large, so we have $\frac{1}{\text{small + large}} \approx \frac{1}{\text{large}},$ which is *small* (what we know is the case), whereas what you suggest would have us using $\frac{1}{\text{small + large}} \approx \frac{1}{\text{small}},$ which is *large* (what we know is NOT the case). This is meant to be descriptive, so not all the small's are necessarily equal and not all the large's are necessarily equal. Also, $(U + V)^{-1} \neq U^{-1} + V^{-1},$ which you'll be using at some point if you tried to write everything out explicitly to obtain what you're thinking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have
$$(ax^{-2}+bx^{-4})^{-1} = \dfrac{x^4}{ax^2+b}\approx \dfrac{x^4}{b}\left(1-\dfrac{a}{b}x^2+O(x^4)\right)=O(x^4)$$
by Taylor's approximation.

Comment: But for small $x$, doesn't it seem that $a^{-1}x^2$ will be dominant?